# How to create SOAP request - PHP

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

My client uses a provider that uses SOAP for their services, and I don't know anything about it. I've read through documentation, SoapClient and a lot more.

How can I get this to work?

**Sample request**

```
POST /itravel/API/WebService/iTravelAPI_3_0.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: divingtravel.itravelsoftware.com
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Header>
    <AuthHeader xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <Username>string</Username>
      <Password>string</Password>
    </AuthHeader>
  </soap12:Header>
  <soap12:Body>
    <GetRegions xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <getRegionsParameters>
        <CountryID>int</CountryID>
        <ObjectTypeID>unsignedByte</ObjectTypeID>
        <ObjectTypeGroupID>unsignedByte</ObjectTypeGroupID>
        <CategoryID>int</CategoryID>
        <LanguageID>string</LanguageID>
        <SeasonID>int</SeasonID>
      </getRegionsParameters>
    </GetRegions>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

**Sample response**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <GetRegionsResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <GetRegionsResult>
        <Region>
          <CountryID>int</CountryID>
          <RegionID>int</RegionID>
          <RegionName>string</RegionName>
          <RegionNameTranslationList>
            <Translation xsi:nil="true" />
            <Translation xsi:nil="true" />
          </RegionNameTranslationList>
          <Description>string</Description>
          <DescriptionTranslationList>
            <Translation xsi:nil="true" />
            <Translation xsi:nil="true" />
          </DescriptionTranslationList>
          <RegionCode>string</RegionCode>
          <CountryCode>string</CountryCode>
          <PhotoList>
            <Photo xsi:nil="true" />
            <Photo xsi:nil="true" />
          </PhotoList>
          <ShortDescription>string</ShortDescription>
          <ShortDescriptionTranslationList>
            <Translation xsi:nil="true" />
            <Translation xsi:nil="true" />
          </ShortDescriptionTranslationList>
          <Title>string</Title>
          <TitleTranslationList>
            <Translation xsi:nil="true" />
            <Translation xsi:nil="true" />
          </TitleTranslationList>
          <SEODescription>string</SEODescription>
          <SEODescriptionTranslationList>
            <Translation xsi:nil="true" />
            <Translation xsi:nil="true" />
          </SEODescriptionTranslationList>
          <KeyWords>string</KeyWords>
          <KeyWordsTranslationList>
            <Translation xsi:nil="true" />
            <Translation xsi:nil="true" />
          </KeyWordsTranslationList>
        </Region>
      </GetRegionsResult>
    </GetRegionsResponse>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

Currently I have been trying to follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22672018/how-to-create-soap-1-2-request), but it doesn't write out anything.

My current code, trying to follow the link above:

```
<?php
$client = new SoapClient("http://divingtravel.itravelsoftware.com/itravel/API/WebService/iTravelAPI_3_0.asmx", array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_2));
$result = $client('GetCategories');

var_dump($result);
?>
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Updated link and provided current code.

Comment: What does your code that isn't working look like?

Comment: So far, SOAP handling with PHP has been such a huge problem for me. You should try checking SoapServer doc first http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapserver.php and see if it can help you. I had to install SoapUI and hardcode all requests as strings inside PHP

Comment: @CapitanFindus You shouldn't need to be handling XML strings when you're using `SoapClient`. If you're doing that, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: _"I've read through documentation, SoapClient and a lot more"_ - So what happens when you try with SoapClient? If you show us the code and explain what actually happens, it would be a bit easier (even though it's never easy when it comes to Soap).

Comment: My mistake. I don't have so much code, and I've been trying and following another stackoverflow link. I have provided a link in the description and also updated with my code

Comment: First off, the XML request you posted is not the same as the service you're trying to fetch. It also looks like you need to add AuthHeader to be able to access that service (at least for the sample you posted).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson alright, that makes sense. Is this something I should provide with __setSoapHeaders?

Comment: That sounds like it might work.

Comment: @jjok I wasn't handling the SOAP Server, misconfiguring it had me to use that (I agree with that) s**t method

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the request as an object. You can also do it with an array.

```
$getRegionsRequest = new \stdClass();
$getRegionsRequest->getRegionsParameters = new \stdClass();
$getRegionsRequest->getRegionsParameters->CountryID = 123;
$getRegionsRequest->getRegionsParameters->ObjectTypeID= 123;
$getRegionsRequest->getRegionsParameters->ObjectTypeGroupID = 123;
$getRegionsRequest->getRegionsParameters->CategoryID = 123;
$getRegionsRequest->getRegionsParameters->LanguageID = 'something';
$getRegionsRequest->getRegionsParameters->SeasonID = 123;

$client = new SoapClient("http://divingtravel.itravelsoftware.com/itravel/API/WebService/iTravelAPI_3_0.asmx", array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_2));
$getRegionsResponse = $client->GetRegions($getRegionsRequest);

var_dump($getRegionsResponse);
```